# From PROGMEM to Flash Memory of Arduino

Tags: arduino, avr

I am trying to get some help because I'm moving someone else's code (that uses a PROGMEM) to my Flash Memory...

Visit http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=218899.0

So, here are my questions:
This is the original code segment:

```
prog_uint8_t Image[ImageColumns][LEDEights] PROGMEM = {{ 
B11111111, B11111111, B11111111, B11111111, B11111111, B11111111, B11111111, B11111111,     
B11111111  }
  , {
B11111111, B10110111, B10111001, B11111111, B11111111, B11111111, B11111111, B11111111,                 B11111111  }};
```

This is my revised code:

```
const int Image[ImageColumns][LEDEights] = {};
```

I tried to compile it using other's laptops, and then it wored actually, but I noticed and learned that PROGRAM is impossible for chainging outoutl. Is my revision correct?>?

I can't fully say that the whole code will work, because of this: (I know this has something to do with AVR-GCC bla bla bla progmem, right? I've read about it a while ago just for a minute.).

Code:
    prog_uint8_t imageEights = pgm_read_byte(&(Image[column][eight]));

If this won't work, how to read byte from SRAM then?

Comment: Using PROGMEM means that the data resides in the FLASH memory. You probably mean you want to put the data into the SRAM. However, maybe the author of the code had a good reason to put the data into FLASH because SRAM is very limited? What is wrong with the existing code? Why do you want to revise it? Does it improve something?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. If you just want to switch from using PROGMEM to Flash memory with that existing code what you have is close - **except you are initializing that var to an empty array.**

You are correct that you can't change PROGMEM at runtime.

This works:

```
int image[][9]= {
  { 
    B11111111,
    B11111111, 
    B11111111, 
    B11111111, 
    B11111111, 
    B11111111, 
    B11111111, 
    B11111111,     
    B11111111  }
  ,
  {
    B11111111, 
    B10110111, 
    B10111001, 
    B11111111, 
    B11111111, 
    B11111111, 
    B11111111, 
    B11111111,                 
    B11111111  }
};
```